# CLLocation equivalent on .Net

Tags: c#, ios

I would like to send a CLLocation object to my .Net backend and store it on azure table. Is there a pre-defined (or maybe a native) type on .Net that will suit my needs?

Comment: CLLocation is a class and as such has properties that are custom to the definition of that class. It is very improbable that another framework would mimic this class to the extent that the data would be automatically interchangeable. That being said, it would not be difficult at all to create a custom class in C# that had the same properties as CLLocation and could encode/decode them appropriately to allow for cross framework data exchange.

Comment: @RicPerrott I know... I figured that, someone, somewhere, would've done that already...

Comment: If only that was always the case!  :-)